# Rodar Elemento ao Clicar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Boas eu estou com 1 problema, estou usando o accordion do jquery que ao clicar em uma lista, ela expande e mostras todas as informação, assosicadas a esse "projeto".

O meu problema e q eu tenho uma seta para mostar q a lista expande, e quando a lista esta expandida, a seta roda e fica virada para cima, o problema e quando clico em cima dos elementos da dessa lista expandida a seta volta a fazer o rotate.

Mas eu com texto, talvez nao consiga explicar bem o problema, entao consegui reproduzir o probelma no JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/jzneur48/3/

Código do link

```js
$(function(){
  $("#projeto_1").click(function(){
    console.log("#rotate_1");
    $("#rotate_1").toggleClass("rotate");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav > li > a").on("click", function(e){
   if($(this).parent().has("ul")) {
     e.preventDefault();
   }
   
   if(!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
    
    $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
    $(this).addClass("open");
    
   }else if($(this).hasClass("open")) {
    $(this).removeClass("open");
    $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
   }
  });
  
 });
```

```css
.rotate{
 transform: rotate(180deg);
    margin-top: 7px;
}

#nav {
  display: block;
  width: 280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  box-shadow: 3px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
 
#nav > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 18px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #14597C;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  background-color: #D0DBE5;
}
#nav > li > a:hover, #nav > li > a.open {
    color: #e9e9e9;
    border-bottom-color: #384f76;
    background-color: #14597c;
}

#nav li ul { display: none; background: #4a5b78; }
 
#nav li ul li a {
  display: block;
  background: none;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #e3e7f1;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000;
}
#nav li ul li a:hover {
  background: #394963;
}
```

```html
<script src="/js/scriptbreaker-multiple-accordion-1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul style="padding: 0;list-style-type: none; width:100%" id="nav">
  <li class="ui-state-default" ordem="<?=$i+1?>" id="projeto_1"> 
    <a style="text-align: left;" href="#">
    <b> Projeto 1 (Apenas ao clicar aqui, é que a seta deveria de alterar ) </b>
    <i id="rotate_1" style="float:right" class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>      
     </a>
    <ul style="padding: 0;">
      <p style="height:50px; margin:0">
        Teste (Ao clicar aqui a seta nao devia de altarer, nao deveria de fazer o rotate )
      </p>
    </ul>
    
 </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu seletor `$("#projeto_1").click(function(){` está errado. Vc pos o evento de click na `LI` inteira, e tem que ser no link dentro da `LI`.

deveria ser assim `$("#projeto_1 > a").click(function(){` e vai funcionar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da imagem acima

```js
$(function(){
  $("#projeto_1 a").click(function(){
    console.log("#rotate_1");
    $("#rotate_1").toggleClass("rotate");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav > li > a").on("click", function(e){
   if($(this).parent().has("ul")) {
     e.preventDefault();
   }
   
   if(!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
    
    $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
    $(this).addClass("open");
    
   }else if($(this).hasClass("open")) {
    $(this).removeClass("open");
    $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
   }
  });
  
 });
```

```css
.rotate{
 transform: rotate(180deg);
    margin-top: 7px;
}

#nav {
  display: block;
  width: 280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  box-shadow: 3px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
 
#nav > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 18px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #14597C;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  background-color: #D0DBE5;
}
#nav > li > a:hover, #nav > li > a.open {
    color: #e9e9e9;
    border-bottom-color: #384f76;
    background-color: #14597c;
}

#nav li ul { display: none; background: #4a5b78; }
 
#nav li ul li a {
  display: block;
  background: none;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #e3e7f1;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000;
}
#nav li ul li a:hover {
  background: #394963;
}
```

```html
<script src="/js/scriptbreaker-multiple-accordion-1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul style="padding: 0;list-style-type: none; width:100%" id="nav">
  <li class="ui-state-default" ordem="<?=$i+1?>" id="projeto_1"> 
    <a style="text-align: left;" href="#">
    <b> Projeto 1 (Apenas ao clicar aqui, é que a seta deveria de alterar ) </b>
    <i id="rotate_1" style="float:right" class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>      
     </a>
    <ul style="padding: 0;">
      <p style="height:50px; margin:0">
        Teste (Ao clicar aqui a seta nao devia de altarer, nao deveria de fazer o rotate )
      </p>
    </ul>
    
 </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: perfeito, muito obrigado funcionou corretamente sem qualquer problema

Comment: @Ricardo tranquilo jovem, é que a forma como vc coloco o seletor ele estava pegando a LI inteira, vc tinha que colocar o evento ara ser disparado apenas clicando no link A. Valeu a força, abs